# Tkinter button responds to event handler even after disabled

Tags: python, tkinter

I configured my button to be disabled

```
self.button.configure(state = Tk.DISABLED)
```

However, when clicking the button, although visually I don't see the animation, the callback bound to it still gets called.

```
self.button.bind('<Button-1>', myhandler)
```

Is this by design? I tested this on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter is working as designed. The real problem is that you aren't using tkinter as it was designed to be used.

If you use the `command` option, tkinter will honor the state of the button. If you use `bind`, you are in essence telling tkinter that you will handle all the details of handling the click.